# Safe and parsimonious creation of customised (non-comp) textual citation commands when using authoryear-comp

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I've been trying to create custom variants of Biblatex's `\textcite`, `\textcites`, `\Textcite` and `\Textcites` commands. Although I have managed to come up with some code which appears to more-or-less work, I have two reservations:

1. I am not sure whether it is safe.
2. It seems unlikely to be the most elegant or parsimonious solution.

Is there a better way to do this?

Much of the code below consists of renamed copies of `bibmacro`s etc. from the Biblatex package, especially from `authoryear.cbx` and, to a lesser extent, from `biblatex.def`.

The reason for this is that I typically use the `authoryear-comp` citation style, which uses different definitions. However, that code seems much more complex and I could not figure out how to create my custom citation commands easily.

Since I do not want the `comp` effect for these particular commands, I looked at the much simpler examples in `authoryear.cbx` and based my commands on its definitions of the `textcite` macro and the `\textcite` command.

However, these definitions naturally assume the corresponding definitions of various macros etc. are taken from the same style. So, in order to make this work, I needed copies of those definitions from `authoryear.cbx` and `biblatex.def`.

Since I don't want to mess up `authoryear-comp.cbx`'s definitions of the standard citation commands, I renamed these copies and used the renamed versions to work around the problem.

But this is basically a brute-force-and-ignorance approach and surely not the better for it.

I've left some annotations in the code to indicate which particular Biblatex file the specific chunk of code is a (modified) copy of. I'm sorry it is not more minimal, but these are the minimum bits I seemed to need in testing.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\newcounter{cfrcitereadingtotal}% stand-in for textcitetotal
\newcommand*{\iffinalcfrcitereadingdelim}{\iflastcitekey}% copy of \iffinalcitedelim from authoryear.cbx
\newbibmacro*{cfr:readingciteyear}{% copy of citeyear from authoryear.cbx
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}{%
      \usebibmacro{cite:label}%
    }{%
      \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
    }%
  }{%
    \usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
  }%
}
\newbibmacro*{cfr:readingcite:postnote}{% copy of textcite:postnote from authoryear.cbx
  \iffieldundef{postnote}{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}{%
      \bibcloseparen
    }{}%
  }{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}{%
      \setunit{\postnotedelim}%
    }{%
      \setunit{\addspace\bibopenparen}%
    }%
    \printfield{postnote}%
    \bibcloseparen
  }%
}
%% this is basically a straight copy but using a custom counter so it doesn't get decremented the way the textcite equivalent does in authoryear-comp.cbx
\newcommand*{\cfrcitereadingdelim}{% modified from \textcitedelim in biblatex.def
  \iffinalcfrcitereadingdelim{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{cfrcitereadingtotal}}{2}{%
      \iftextcitepunct{\finalandsemicolon}{\finalandcomma}%
    }{}%
    \addspace\bibstring{and}%
  }{%
    \iftextcitepunct{\addsemicolon}{\addcomma}%
  }%
  \space
}
%% this is the actual specialised bit, but based on textcite from the simpler style
\newbibmacro*{cfr:readingcite}{% modified from textcite in authoryear.cbx
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
  \setunit{%
    \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
    \addspace\bibopenparen
  }%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}{%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}%
  }{}%
  \usebibmacro{cfr:readingciteyear}%
}
%% this uses the new macro cfr:readingcite and the copies of the other relevant bits from authoryear, avoiding the authoryear-comp textcite complexities
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citereading}% modified from \textcite in authoryear.cbx
{% precode
  \boolfalse{cbx:parens}%
}{% loopcode
  \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \iffirstcitekey{%
    \setcounter{cfrcitereadingtotal}{1}%
  }{%
    \stepcounter{cfrcitereadingtotal}%
    \cfrcitereadingdelim
  }%
  \usebibmacro{cfr:readingcite}%
}{% sepcode
  \ifbool{cbx:parens}{%
    \bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}%
  }{}%
}{% postcode
  \usebibmacro{cfr:readingcite:postnote}%
}
\newrobustcmd{\Citereading}{\bibsentence\citereading}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\citereadings}{\citereading}{}
\newrobustcmd{\Citereadings}{\bibsentence\citereadings}

\begin{document}
  \citereading{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \citereading[pre][post]{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \citereading[][post]{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \citereading[post]{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \citereading[pre][]{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \citereading{westfahl:space}

  \citereading[pre][post]{westfahl:space}

  \citereading[][post]{westfahl:space}

  \citereading[post]{westfahl:space}

  \citereading[pre][]{westfahl:space}

  \Citereading{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \Citereading[pre][post]{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \Citereading[][post]{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \Citereading[pre]{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \Citereading[pre][]{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \Citereading{westfahl:space}

  \Citereading[pre][post]{westfahl:space}

  \Citereading[][post]{westfahl:space}

  \Citereading[pre]{westfahl:space}

  \Citereading[pre][]{westfahl:space}

  \citereadings{westfahl:space}{gillies}{doody}

  \citereadings(pre)(post)[pre1][post1]{westfahl:space}[pre2][post2]{gillies}[pre3][post3]{doody}

  \citereadings[][post1]{westfahl:space}[][post2]{gillies}[post3]{doody}

  \citereadings[post1]{westfahl:space}{gillies}[post3]{doody}

  \citereadings[pre1][]{westfahl:space}[pre2][]{gillies}[pre3][post3]{doody}

  \Citereadings(pre)(post){westfahl:space}{gillies}{doody}

  \Citereadings[pre1][post1]{westfahl:space}[post2]{gillies}[pre3][]{doody}

  \Citereadings[][post1]{westfahl:space}{gillies}[pre3][]{doody}

  \Citereadings[pre1]{westfahl:space}{gillies}{doody}

  \Citereadings(pre)(post)[pre1][]{westfahl:space}{gillies}{doody}

\end{document}
```

Sample output (which seems to be as I'd expect - the results are not what I'm worried about!):

[image: sample output]

Comment: Before I have a closer look at the code (which by what I have seen so far seems fine; I would probably take a similar approach, but I would probably not be that careful ...) please allow me to comment on one of my pet hates: `citestyle=authoryear-comp,bibstyle=authoryear` is equivalent to the shorter and easier-to-digest `style=authoryear-comp`.

Comment: Fancy `\textcite` macros seem to be Audrey's forte from what I gather. Unfortunately, she hasn't been very active here for the last few months. I'm sure her answer would be much more enlightening than anything I could ever come up with; still I have cooked something up that might be of interest.

Comment: The thing is that I find `citestyle=authoryear-comp,bibstyle=authoryear` clearer when reading the source. Unlike `style=authoryear-comp`, it tells me precisely which `.cbx` and `.bbx` files I'm using. That is, technically, the shorter version does, too. But because the `.bbx` does nothing but load another `.bbx` in that case, it is less directly useful. Shorter isn't always better, in my view. Shorter is *prima facie* better, but the reasons in favour are defeasible. And I find the longer version *easier* to digest *because* of the greater verbosity.

Comment: I've edited the example since you say it is a pet hate, but I'm not changing my own code unless there is some reason to prefer greater opacity in this case.

Comment: That is a fair point. Of course then you need to know that the `bibstyle` and `citestyle` play together nicely. (And in a way it also needs the prior knowledge that `authoryear-comp.bbx` does not define anything that `authoryear.bbx` doesn't.) I appreciate your changing the MWE, my aversion comes from seeing things like `style=alphabetic,citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=numeric` (I might be exaggerating, but I have certainly seen all three used together with different arguments) which is very confusing indeed, especially for less experienced users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\textcite`-family of macros is in some of the more challenging styles implemented with very advanced code. Modifications of those commands can easily accumulate vast numbers of lines of code.

That said, your solution looks very safe to me. Anything that might interfere with the usual cite commands in your style has been renamed, so clashes there are quite unlikely.

Of course the length is a bit overwhelming at first, but that was to be expected.

The big advantage of your solution is that copying all commands allows the code to work with almost all styles.

---

**This part of the answer assumes you always use `-comp`-type styles**

I think, however, that it should be possible to reduce the need to replicate so many macros by keeping close to the definition of `\textcite` in `authoryear-comp` and modifying just a few bits.

This solution, then depends on some of the structure and macros defined in `authoryear-comp` and `authoryear-icomp`, with a short modification (add `\providebibmacro{citeyear}{\printfield{year}}`) it can also be used with `authortitle-(ti)comp`.

My main idea was that since essentially we want to disable the `-comp` feature we only need to call `cite:reinit`, this macro makes `biblatex` forget the last name and year so that citations cannot be compressed any more.

Firstly `cfr:readingcite` is a simplified version of `authoryear-comp` `textcite` with the necessary bits (`printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}`) added (it was also possible to use `citeyear` directly)

```
\newbibmacro*{cfr:readingcite}{% modified from textcite in authoryear-comp.cbx
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
  \setunit{%
    \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
    \addspace\bibopenparen}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{citeyear}%
  \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
  \textcitedelim}}
```

Then we simply replicate all the facilities that make `\textcite` possible in `authoryear-comp`.

The "major" change is adding `cite:reinit` to `\cbx@readingcite` (the macro that does the real citing) in order to disable the `-comp` behaviour

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@readingcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:reinit}%
   \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cfr:readingcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
```

The rest is the original code from `authoryear-comp` slightly renamed and with one `\cbx@lasthash` test dropped

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citereading}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@readingcite]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \stepcounter{textcitetotal}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@readingcites}{\cbx@readingcite}{}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\citereadings}[\cbx@textcites@init\cbx@readingcites]{\citereading}{}

\newrobustcmd{\Citereading}{\bibsentence\citereading}
\newrobustcmd{\Citereadings}{\bibsentence\citereadings}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,bibstyle=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{cfr:readingcite}{% modified from textcite in authoryear-comp.cbx
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
  \setunit{%
    \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
    \addspace\bibopenparen}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{citeyear}%
  \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
  \textcitedelim}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@readingcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:reinit}%
   \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cfr:readingcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citereading}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@readingcite]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \stepcounter{textcitetotal}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cbx@readingcites}{\cbx@readingcite}{}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\citereadings}[\cbx@textcites@init\cbx@readingcites]{\citereading}{}

\newrobustcmd{\Citereading}{\bibsentence\citereading}
\newrobustcmd{\Citereadings}{\bibsentence\citereadings}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \citereading{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}

  \citereading{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}

  \citereading{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}

  \citereading{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \citereading[pre][post]{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \citereading[][post]{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \citereading[post]{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \citereading[pre][]{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \citereading{westfahl:space}

  \citereading[pre][post]{westfahl:space}

  \citereading[][post]{westfahl:space}

  \citereading[post]{westfahl:space}

  \citereading[pre][]{westfahl:space}

  \Citereading{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \Citereading[pre][post]{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \Citereading[][post]{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \Citereading[pre]{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \Citereading[pre][]{westfahl:space,gillies,doody}

  \Citereading{westfahl:space}

  \Citereading[pre][post]{westfahl:space}

  \Citereading[][post]{westfahl:space}

  \Citereading[pre]{westfahl:space}

  \Citereading[pre][]{westfahl:space}

  \citereadings{westfahl:space}{gillies}{doody}

  \citereadings(pre)(post)[pre1][post1]{westfahl:space}[pre2][post2]{gillies}[pre3][post3]{doody}

  \citereadings[][post1]{westfahl:space}[][post2]{gillies}[post3]{doody}

  \citereadings[post1]{westfahl:space}{gillies}[post3]{doody}

  \citereadings[pre1][]{westfahl:space}[pre2][]{gillies}[pre3][post3]{doody}

  \Citereadings(pre)(post){westfahl:space}{gillies}{doody}

  \Citereadings[pre1][post1]{westfahl:space}[post2]{gillies}[pre3][]{doody}

  \Citereadings[][post1]{westfahl:space}{gillies}[pre3][]{doody}

  \Citereadings[pre1]{westfahl:space}{gillies}{doody}

  \Citereadings(pre)(post)[pre1][]{westfahl:space}{gillies}{doody}

\end{document}
```

[image: details of MWE output]

Comment: Very impressive! (The mere fact that you seem to understand `authoryear-comp`'s `\textcite` gets you this response.) I am not sure whether to use this or my longer solution, though. I've added that to `biblatex.cfg` which I think will be reasonably safe even if I use a different citation style - at least if that style is a relatively similar one e.g. `authoryear` rather than `authoryear-comp`. Is there a way of making the code conditional on the loaded style and, if so, would it be better to load your code conditionally in case `-comp` is used? (`authoryear-comp` is my usual default.)

Comment: Rereading my question, I probably could have been clearer about the `typically` not meaning `always`. I was testing with `authoryear-comp` because that's what I usually use, which was want led me to the differences between `\textcite` in `authoryear-comp` and `authoryear`.

Comment: @cfr *Seem* is the right word there. The solution above depends quite heavily on the infrastructure set up by `authoryear-comp`. It definitely won't work for `authoryear` alone (`\tetxcite` has a much more tame definition there, so some auxiliary macros are missing), it works with `authoryear-icomp`. With `authortitle-*comp` styles it would probably also work as soon as we define `citeyear` (`\providebibmacro{citeyear}{\printfield{year}}` is safe). The structure of `\textcite` that we used is really one of the `*comp` and `verbose` styles, other implementations are far simpler.

Comment: If you really are after a command for all styles, your approach is probably the safest. One could think about using standard names and `\providebibmacro`, which still avoids clashes and falls back to a reasonable standard if the macro is not defined by the style. I don't think you would benefit from using my code with `-comp` styles and yours with the others: the output is the same and the relative shortness of my code compared to yours is in a way lost if you use both conditionally on the style, that just adds opportunities for mistakes to sneak in.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like compatibility with other `authoryear` styles. Anything beyond that I don't expect to necessarily work. If I need one of those styles, I'll deal with any problems which arise. But I do sometimes switch to another `authoryear` style for one reason or another, and code which will work in that case has a significant advantage.

Comment: I really, really, really appreciate your help with all my questions about Biblatex. You probably have no idea how helpful it is.